# Using Edge.js in Typescript to call an API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, edge.js

This is my first time using Angular, Edge.js or calling an API. I'm not sure if I'm doing things right, but I'm surely doing something wrong because it's not working.

To get the data from the API written in C# I'm using Edge.js in a service in my Angular project.

data.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';
import * as edge from "edge";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

  getData(type: string, method: string) {
    let data = edge.func({
      assemblyFile: 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Siemens\Automation\Simatic OAM\bin\CC.CommonInterfaces.dll',
      typeName: `CC.CommonInterfaces.${type}`,
      methodName: `${method}`
    });

    return data(null, function(error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    });
  }

}
```

Then I'm simply calling the getData method with the right parameters in a component like this:

```
onClickTestAPI() {
  this.dataSrv.getData("IState", "IsTunnelActive");
}
```

But when running the web server, the console output shows this:

```
core.js:4002 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected token '<'
  Evaluating https://localhost:8888/edge
  Loading ccui/ccui.umd.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Qe (system.js:4)
    at system.js:4
    at T (system.js:4)
    at T.h (system.js:4)
    at T (system.js:4)
    at system.js:4
    at system.js:4
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:26255)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
    at zone.js:762
    at rejected (tslib.es6.js:69)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:26255)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:910
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26246)
```

There isn't even an API response (or at least I can't find it).

Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: That usually means you're trying to parse the response body as if it was JSON, but it was HTML or XML.

Comment: @jonrsharpe where can I define how I want to parse the response? Do I need to change the parse to HTML or do I need to change the response to JSON to fix this?

Comment: I haven't used edge, so I can't tell you that. I also don't know if you were *expecting* JSON, and there's an e.g. proxy issue in between, or the parsing is actually wrong.

Comment: @slebetman yeah I'm rendering it on the server. I have the client side and server side. The edge is included in the client side though. Do I need to add it to the server side and if yes how do they communicate then?

Comment: The edge cannot be included in the client side. It won't work. There are a limited number of ways browsers can communicate with something and almost all of it is HTTP based: loading script, img, style etc. tags (this is the basis of JSONP), ajax (XMLHttpRequest, fetch etc), loading iframes, communications via plugins (eg. Java, Flash, Silverlight etc - but note that Safari and Chrome no longer supports this - that's roughly 80% of web users can no longer use plugins) and websockets. Browsers cannot load dll directly - that would be a security risk

Comment: @jonrsharpe - He's trying to load a DLL in a browser